# What happens if we change partition key in kinesis?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Consider we have more than one shard and partition keys of type X , now we changed partitionkeys to type Y does Kinesis redistribute the records in shards based on new PartitionKey or it will leave the old records intact and distribute new records based on new PartitionKey?

Answer (score 0):

Once the records are written they cannot be changed. Also, partition key will be passed on a per record basis(when you write them to kinesis). Therefore, if you change the partition key while writing a record, it may go to a different shard. This does change the state of older records. They will be intact in the shard they were written to.